# Preprocessor in cabal file

Tags: haskell, cabal, preprocessor

I need to use the preprocessor in the cabal file of Haskell project.
Like this:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src

  exposed-modules:     Application
                     , ApplicationData
#ifdef ModFest
                     , Foundation 
#endif
                     , EConsole.Coloring
                     , EConsole.Marking
                     , Import
```

How is it possible to use preprocessor in cabal file?

Thank you!

Comment: Cabal has its own (primitive) support for conditionals. (Search for "conditionals" in [the user guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html) and take a look at the `flag(name)` option in particular.)

Comment: Thank you. I implemented it.